# Redirect from Express API Call in React App

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, redirect

I have a route defined in my React App which hosts the following component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import _ from 'lodash';
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';
import { actions as redirectActions } from '../../state/actions/redirect';

class MyRedirector extends PureComponent {
    componentDidMount() {
        const { redirect, match } = this.props;
        redirect(match.params.someData);
    }

    render() {
        return <div />;
    }
}

MyRedirector = connect(state => ({}), { ...redirectActions })(
    MyRedirector
);

export default MyRedirector;
```

I'm making a call to a backend API as follows:

```
const redirect = someData => async dispatch => {
    await axios
            .get(
                `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/someRoute/${someData}`,
                {}
            )
            .then(data => {})
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('ERROR', error);
            });
```

In this route, which is hosted on a Node.js express server, I run the following code:

```
 res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', req.get('origin'));
 res.redirect(
   new URL(
     `${req.get('origin')}/somePath/${
          someObject.data
        }/blabla?someQueryParam=${someData}`
   )
 );
```

The desired flow is as follows:

1. User accesses my frontend route which hosts the redirect component
2. Axios request made to backend
3. Backend responds with redirect
4. Frontend redirects user to redirect URL from backend

I'm not sure how to get this to work with the code above - in my network tab I see a 302 redirect from the API call, I also see an attempt to load the redirect URL, but that fails with a CORS error - no redirect on the page itself occurs.

I'm pretty sure there's a better way of achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to just route the user after a successful api call you can use history props from the react-router-dom

```
const redirect = someData => async dispatch => {
    await axios
            .get(
                `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL}/api/someRoute/${someData}`,
                {}
            )
            .then(data => {
               //check for the success case here using if
              this?.props?.history?.push(your desired url)
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('ERROR', error);
            });
```

If you get any history/push is undefined you need to wrap the component in the HOC provided by the react-router-dom.

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'; 

export default withRouter(MyRedirector);
```

Comment: my desired URL is coming from the backend through the redirect call - are you suggesting that instead of redirecting in the backend, I return a code 200 with the redirectUrl in the body and then parse it out in the action then block?

Comment: yeah or send the url as a response from the backend and update as ```this?.props?.history?.push(data.url)```